# Trying to go from hierarchy to flat table in XML using XLST

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using Xignite to get data in XML. Currently, I've got a call that returns this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ArrayOfFundNAV xmlns="http://www.xignite.com/services/">
  <FundNAV>
    <Outcome>Success</Outcome>
    <Identity>Request</Identity>
    <Delay>0.016001</Delay>
    <Security>
      <Outcome>Success</Outcome>
      <Delay>0</Delay>
      <CIK>N/A</CIK>
      <Cusip>018528513</Cusip>
      <Symbol>ABNOX</Symbol>
      <ISIN>US0185285139</ISIN>
      <Valoren>10967026</Valoren>
      <Name>Alliancebernstein Bond Inflation Strategy Class </Name>
      <Market>FUNDS</Market>
      <CategoryOrIndustry>Inflation-Protected Bond</CategoryOrIndustry>
    </Security>
    <Date>2/19/2014</Date>
    <Last>10.72</Last>
    <Open>10.72</Open>
    <LastClose>10.74</LastClose>
    <ChangeFromOpen>0</ChangeFromOpen>
    <PercentChangeFromOpen>0</PercentChangeFromOpen>
    <ChangeFromLastClose>-0.02</ChangeFromLastClose>
    <PercentChangeFromLastClose>-0.186</PercentChangeFromLastClose>
  </FundNAV>
  <FundNAV>
    <Outcome>Success</Outcome>
    <Message>An NAV is not yet available for the date you requested (2/19/2014). The system looked for the closest previous closing date (6/10/2011).</Message>
    <Delay>0</Delay>
    <Security>
      <Outcome>Success</Outcome>
      <Message>This security is no longer listed.</Message>
      <Delay>0</Delay>
      <CIK>0000353447</CIK>
      <Cusip>014470405</Cusip>
      <Symbol>ABPXX</Symbol>
      <ISIN>US0144704055</ISIN>
      <Valoren>2824817</Valoren>
      <Name>Cash Reserves Fd Inc. Prime Institutional Shar </Name>
      <Market>FUNDS</Market>
      <CategoryOrIndustry>Money Market-Taxable</CategoryOrIndustry>
    </Security>
    <Date>6/10/2011</Date>
    <Last>0.01</Last>
    <Open>0.01</Open>
    <LastClose>0.09</LastClose>
    <ChangeFromOpen>0</ChangeFromOpen>
    <PercentChangeFromOpen>0</PercentChangeFromOpen>
    <ChangeFromLastClose>-0.08</ChangeFromLastClose>
    <PercentChangeFromLastClose>-88.889</PercentChangeFromLastClose>
  </FundNAV>
  <FundNAV>
    <Outcome>Success</Outcome>
    <Delay>0</Delay>
    <Security>
      <Outcome>Success</Outcome>
      <Delay>0</Delay>
      <CIK>0000003794</CIK>
      <Cusip>018528612</Cusip>
      <Symbol>ABQIX</Symbol>
      <ISIN>US0185286129</ISIN>
      <Valoren>2089748</Valoren>
      <Name>Alliancebernstein Bond Fd  Alliancebernstein Int </Name>
      <Market>FUNDS</Market>
      <CategoryOrIndustry>Intermediate-Term Bond</CategoryOrIndustry>
    </Security>
    <Date>2/19/2014</Date>
    <Last>11.03</Last>
    <Open>11.03</Open>
    <LastClose>11.04</LastClose>
    <ChangeFromOpen>0</ChangeFromOpen>
    <PercentChangeFromOpen>0</PercentChangeFromOpen>
    <ChangeFromLastClose>-0.01</ChangeFromLastClose>
    <PercentChangeFromLastClose>-0.091</PercentChangeFromLastClose>
  </FundNAV>
</ArrayOfFundNAV>
```

I'm then trying to transform it using this:

```
<xslt:stylesheet xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csw-xform="http://www.compositesw.com/2003/xform" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.xignite.com/services/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
  <xslt:template match="/">
    <xslt:variable name="_Outcome"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Message"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Identity"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Delay"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Date"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_LastVal"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_OpenVal"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_LastClose"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_ChangeFromOpen"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_PercentChangeFromOpen"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_ChangeFromLastClose"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_PercentChangeFromLastClose"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_Outcome"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_Message"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_Identity"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_Delay"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_CIK"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_Cusip"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_Symbol"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_ISIN"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_Valoren"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_Name"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_Market"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_Security_CategOrIndustry"/>
    <xslt:element name="results">
      <xslt:for-each select="ns1:ArrayOfFundNAV">
        <xslt:for-each select="ns1:FundNAV">
          <xslt:variable name="_Outcome" select="ns1:Outcome"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_Message" select="ns1:Message"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_Identity" select="ns1:Identity"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_Delay" select="ns1:Delay"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_Date" select="ns1:Date"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_LastVal" select="ns1:Last"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_OpenVal" select="ns1:Open"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_LastClose" select="ns1:LastClose"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_ChangeFromOpen" select="ns1:ChangeFromOpen"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_PercentChangeFromOpen" select="ns1:PercentChangeFromOpen"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_ChangeFromLastClose" select="ns1:ChangeFromLastClose"/>
          <xslt:variable name="_PercentChangeFromLastClose" select="ns1:PercentChangeFromLastClose"/>
          <xslt:for-each select="ns1:Security">
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_Outcome" select="ns1:Outcome"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_Message" select="ns1:Message"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_Identity" select="ns1:Identity"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_Delay" select="ns1:Delay"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_CIK" select="ns1:CIK"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_Cusip" select="ns1:Cusip"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_Symbol" select="ns1:Symbol"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_ISIN" select="ns1:ISIN"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_Valoren" select="ns1:Valoren"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_Name" select="ns1:Name"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_Market" select="ns1:Market"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_Security_CategOrIndustry" select="ns1:CategoryOrIndustry"/>
            <xslt:element name="result">
              <xslt:element name="Outcome">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Outcome"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Message">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Message"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Identity">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Identity"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Delay">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Delay"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Date">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Date"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="LastVal">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_LastVal"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="OpenVal">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_OpenVal"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="LastClose">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_LastClose"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="ChangeFromOpen">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_ChangeFromOpen"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="PercentChangeFromOpen">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_PercentChangeFromOpen"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="ChangeFromLastClose">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_ChangeFromLastClose"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="PercentChangeFromLastClose">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_PercentChangeFromLastClose"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_Outcome">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_Outcome"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_Message">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_Message"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_Identity">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_Identity"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_Delay">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_Delay"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_CIK">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_CIK"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_Cusip">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_Cusip"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_Symbol">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_Symbol"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_ISIN">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_ISIN"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_Valoren">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_Valoren"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_Name">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_Name"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_Market">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_Market"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="Security_CategOrIndustry">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_Security_CategOrIndustry"/>
              </xslt:element>
            </xslt:element>
          </xslt:for-each>
        </xslt:for-each>
      </xslt:for-each>
    </xslt:element>
  </xslt:template>
</xslt:stylesheet>
```

What would I need to do to remove the hierarchy and just make it so that it's all flat like a table?

Comment: _"What would I need to do to remove the hierarchy and just make it so that it's all flat like a table?"_ does not make any sense.  Please edit your post and include a sample of what you want to produce from the input.

Comment: I believe you have to add an `xslt` tag for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Will you try this template? See if this fits your requirement.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csw-xform="http://www.compositesw.com/2003/xform" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.xignite.com/services/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="child::*">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{concat(parent::node()/local-name(), '_', local-name())}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It responded with no columns.


The output was this:

'<FundNAV_Outcome>Success</FundNAV_Outcome>'

Comment: Please post your desired output XML.